# Как в golang сослаться на определённый элемент структуры и изменить его?

Tags: golang

Есть список пользователей

```
type User struct {
    Id  int 
    Login string  
    Password string       
    FIO string 
    Online_Count int // Количество подключенных сокетов этого пользователя
}

var UsersList = make(map[int]User)
user := User{1, "Login","Password","FIO",0}
UsersList[Id] = user
```

Но потом нужно изменить Online_Count. Как изменить конкретно в определённом элементе слайса только Online_Count?
Я пока придумал только удалять элемент слайса и записывать с новыми данными, а хочется сослаться на определённое поле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементы map в Go неадресуемы. Поэтому либо используя временную переменную

```
var UserList = make(map[int]User)
user := User{1, "Login", "Password", "FIO", 0}
UserList[Id] = user

...

user = UserList[Id]
user.Online_Count += 1
UserList[Id] = user
```

Либо используя map указателей на пользователей

```
var UserList = make(map[int]*User)
user := User{1, "Login", "Password", "FIO", 0}
UserList[Id] = &user

...

UserList[Id].Online_Count += 1
```